# Android webview pageStarted not detected, facebook unable to cancel share

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview, listener

I am sharing a link using my webview.

"http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + urltoshare;

My code is:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvForFB);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
@Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!loadingFinished) {
          redirect = true;
       }
        loadingFinished = false;

        view.loadUrl(url);
           return true;
       }

    @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           super.onPageFinished(view, url);
           if(!redirect){
               loadingFinished = true;
            }

            if(loadingFinished && !redirect){
              //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
               myrelativebar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               myprogressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);    

            } else{
               redirect = false; 
            }

       }
     @Override
     public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
         super.onPageStarted(view, url, null);

           loadingFinished = false;

           myrelativebar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           myprogressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


       }
       @Override
       public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
   });

    myWebView.loadUrl(attrurl);
```

I need to detect the cancel event on this view. But event on clicking **cancel or Post** **DOES NOT call onpageStarted**, not internally or via debugging for pagestarted.I want to detect cancel event and hide the webview.
Do suggest any workaround.

[image: Share page opened using this link]

Comment: Calling cancel or post may not be loading a URL. As it may be calling some javascript function which could totally escape your 'OnPageStarted()`

Comment: @Darpan Yes but what is the workaround.

Comment: Please don't call loadUrl from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` as it is called for subframes with non-https schemes. If you go to a a page like http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet your code will end up calling view.loadUrl('tel:1234') and you will end up showing an error page, since the webview doesn't know how to load a tel: URL.